# Different Depth In 3D BarChart in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, r, plot, highcharts, r-highcharter

I know that I can set depth of all bars in Highcharts using `depth` property in `column` property of `plotOptions` likes the following code:

```
plotOptions: {
    column : {
        depth: 30 
    }
}
```

Or

```
# in R
hc_plotOptions(column = list(
  depth = 30
)
```

The questions is *how can I set different depth for each bar group in a bar chart* (not one depth for all)? Solution can be in R (Highcharter) or in JS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In core code the `depth` property is always taken from the series object options. Every group consists of the points with the same x values.

These 2 solutions came to my mind:

**1. Modify the core code** so that `depth` values are taken from points' configuration instead:

```
(function(H) {
  (...)

  H.seriesTypes.column.prototype.translate3dShapes = function() {
      (...)    

        point.shapeType = 'cuboid';
        shapeArgs.z = z;
        shapeArgs.depth = point.options.depth; // changed from: shapeArgs.depth = depth;
        shapeArgs.insidePlotArea = true;

      (...) 
  };

})(Highcharts);
```

Series options:

```
  series: [{
    data: [{y: 5, depth: 50}, {y: 2, depth: 100}]
  }, {
    data: [{y: 13, depth: 50}, {y: 1, depth: 100}]
  }]
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/3pkon2Lp/

**Docs page about overwriting core functions:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts

---

**2. Create a separate series for every point.**

`depth` property can be applied to a series so the modification of the core wouldn't be necessary. Every series is shown in legend by default so series will have to be properly connected using `linkedTo` property (so that the user doesn't see as many series as points).

Points can be modified before passing them to the chart constructor or dynamically handled in `chart.events.load`.

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/37sot3am/

```
  load: function() {
    var chart = this,
      newSeries = [],
      merge = Highcharts.merge,
      depths = [10, 100]; // depth values for subsequent x values

    for (var i = chart.series.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      var s = chart.series[i];

      s.data.forEach(function(p, i) {

        // merge point options
        var pointOptions = [merge(p.options, {
          // x value doesn't have to appear in options so it needs to be added manually
          x: p.x
        })];

        // merge series options
        var options = merge(s.options, {
          data: pointOptions,
          depth: depths[i]
        });

        // mimic original series structure in the legend
        if (i) {
          options.linkedTo = ":previous"
        }

        newSeries.push(options);
      });
      s.remove(true);
    }

    newSeries.forEach((s) => chart.addSeries(s));
  }
```

**API reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.linkedTo

Comment: Sure, I've just added demo to my answer.