# How to modify highcharter htmlwidget code

Tags: r, r-highcharter

I want to change the core code of the highcharter in R (the requirement comes from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47983857/3768871)). I want to change core code of the highcharts in R as I know how to modify it in javascript:

```
(function(H) {
  (...)

  H.seriesTypes.column.prototype.translate3dShapes = function() {
      (...)    

        point.shapeType = 'cuboid';
        shapeArgs.z = z;
        shapeArgs.depth = point.options.depth; // changed from: shapeArgs.depth = depth;
        shapeArgs.insidePlotArea = true;

      (...) 
  };

})(Highcharts);
```

Calling this code using `js_typeof` or such as these solutions can't be helpful anymore.

The question is *how to change the core code of the highcharter in R

Answer (score 1):

You can create your custom highchart widget using the following:

- First you can have a minimal widget with `highcharter::highchartzero()`. This custom widget only load highcharts.js.
- Then add the highcharts3d using `highcharter::hc_add_dependency("highcharts-3d.js")`
- Finally you can add the js as a dependency to the widget using `htmltools::htmlDependency` function (internally `hc_add_dependency` uses this function)

The code will be something like (not tested) this:

```
hc <- highcharter::highchartzero() %>% 
  highcharter::hc_add_dependency("highcharts-3d.js")

hc # see the source code and see only highcharts and highcharts-3d is loaded.

# adding depedency
dep <- htmlDependency(
    name = "change-depth",
    version = "1.0.0",
    src = "the/folder/", # absolute path I think!
    script = "your_js_script.js"
  )

hc$dependencies <- c(hc$dependencies, list(dep))

hc # see the source again

hc %>% hc_add_series(...) # add the data
```

Comment: `Error: 'highchartzero' is not an exported object from 'namespace:highcharter'`

Comment: Please, try the devolpment/github version https://github.com/jbkunst/highcharter#installation